# FastApi Sessions for Anonymous Users

Tags: python, security, fastapi

I'm looking for a simple way to achieve this:

Anonymous users access a fastapi service. From a client, a user begins a session and sends a request. The fastapi service captures dependency data from the request. If the user makes further requests during the same session, the dependency data is updated and so on. Ditto for all anonymous users.

<s>Not looking for a cookie solution.</s> In the Get-Current-User method https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/get-current-user/ it says (paraphrasing):

"If you have users, robots, bots, or other systems that log in to your application with an access token, it all works the same."

How does it work for anonymous users? Thanks

Comment: You do need a cookie (or header, if you're willing to do things manually) of some sort to identify the user.

Comment: And the `get_current_user` method you linked uses exactly that - a header to identify the user (which would be `Authorization` with a token bearer). Whether that's a `Cookie` header or a different header would generally be the same thing.

Comment: @MatsLindh The question has been edited to reflect the cookie issue and to focus on anonymous users. Thank-you

Comment: There is no difference. If you want to have a session, you have to have some sort of token. If you want a user to be completely anonymous - i.e. not give them any way of identifying themselves, even as "User KaJEUF8u3UJaHNZUe837ujNZ", you can't track a server side session.

Comment: @MatsLindh Please answer the question with your last comment and will accept as answer. Thanks